# Understanding change detection and async functions in Angular

Tags: angular, asynchronous, data-binding, angular2-changedetection

I am trying to understand the change detection and template updating in Angular. I am actually a little confused.

I have a button and a simple input field. 
When the button is clicked I change the input field's value to "test". Then make an async function which returns immediately. Then I wait for around 4 seconds using a for loop (for testing purposes).

- **What I expect is:** Input field's value becomes "asynched" immediately, since it is an async call.
- **Reality :** Input field's value becomes     "asynched" after 4 seconds.

Code

```ts
  updateField(){
    this.textContentMain.title = "test"
    this.asyncTestFunction();
    for(var i=0;i<3999999999;i++){

    } 
  }

  asyncTestFunction() {
    this._contentSalesTextConfigService.get(this.contentSalesTextConfig).subscribe(item => {
        this.textContentMain.title = "asynced";
    })
  }
```

Template

```html
<button (click)="updateField()">Update</button>
<input  [ngModel]="textContentMain.title" #titleAccessor="ngModel" name="title" id="title"  type="text" >
```

Comment: I could be wrong here but your digest cycle probably won't be executed until the function executes.  Your synchronous function is separate from your for loop, why your for loop is there I am not sure.  My thought though is that for loop is what you're waiting on.

Comment: Asynchronous calls are *always* resolved only after everything in the current context is completed. The get is added to the "to-do list", then the rest of the function runs before that list gets checked for what's next. This is nothing do do with Angular's change detection, which runs as expected when the title value actually gets set.

Comment: thanks a lot @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the flow of execution, This should clear all your doubts

```
// 1. This function will be called as soon as clicked
updateField(){
    this.textContentMain.title = "test" // 2. changes the value
    this.asyncTestFunction(); // 3. call async function
    for(var i=0;i<3999999999;i++){ // 5. start for loop 

    } 
    // 6. end for loop
}

asyncTestFunction() {
    this._contentSalesTextConfigService.get(this.contentSalesTextConfig) // 4. call the http request
    .subscribe(item => {
        this.textContentMain.title = "asynced"; // 7. asap response is received and for loop finish its execution this wiil be executed.
    })
}
```

> Why => 7. asap response is received and for loop finish its execution
>   this wiil be executed. (why it waits for "for loop" to finish)?
>
> For this you have to read event-loop
>   Watch this the best video which
>   can explain the key thing behind the scene:
>
> [What the heck is the event loop anyway?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ)

Comment: Thanks a lot, the for loop is for testing. So that i can detect what happens when. Your response is very clarifying thanks. So as i understand, the asyncTestFunction is executed when it is called and gets the response immediately, but the callback is executed when updateField() function ends its exection..@Vivek

Comment: Nope it will make call to the api , generally api call takes time , in that time angular continue its works , untill api response is get, once the response is received, it will execute the code inside subscribe ( No. 7)

Comment: Lets say for loop set to run for 30 secs. And server responded after 2 secs. As i can see order is still the same @Vivek

Comment: So It will wait for 30sec to update / because of event loop , if there is no for loop then will update it in 2 sec , Please watch the video I have post the link, It will blow your mind.

Comment: Please accept the answer , if its clear your doubts. @rematnarab